# Screen Size of VideoView is changing When playing video in VideoView Android

Tags: android, media-player

When i am  playing video in video view but initially its fine when video starts playing in height automatically decreased(chanded).video view is inside relative layout 
I need Urgent .
Thanks Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hello i also faced this but i set it like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >
    <VideoView
        android:id="@+id/videoview"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true" >
    </VideoView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: because aspect ratio is different than on your screen. Wrap it in some layout again.

Comment: Works like a charm!